# How to send HTTP request and retrieve response in PHP (with fine-tuning of headers)?

Tags: php

I have to send a HTTP request to an URL and retrieve response together with headers. I'm interested not only in page content, but in all headers also. What is the optimal solution? sockets? PEAR libraries are not accessible, PHP configuration is not editable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should use [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

quick sample from the documentation

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.perdu.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to curl is to open a socket using stream_socket_client or fsockopen, write a HTTP request, and read the response. This is more work, but gives full control over the request and response.

Use HTTP/1.0 and not HTTP/1.1. With 1.0, you don't have to worry about chunked transfer encoding or transient connections, and it works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look into [http](https://www.php.net/http) extension.