# How i can make this http post request with php json?

Tags: php, jquery, json, httprequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send HTTP request and retrieve response in PHP (with fine-tuning of headers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468877/how-to-send-http-request-and-retrieve-response-in-php-with-fine-tuning-of-heade)

8.1.4.1 Sample ping request

HTTP request:

```
POST /api/ra/v1/ping HTTP/1.0
Host: app.test.net
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
Content-Type: application/json
"Are you there?"
```

can someone please help me with some php raw example?

Comment: The body of that request is not the JSON that the Content-Type header claims that it should be.

Comment: this request is in the api reference example. But I have no idea how to setup my php file to make this call

Comment: not even clear what goal is... AJAX or php to remote API post? A little more effort put into your question would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try curl
http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

I made the same thing for a game site, where I would have to constantly log in to use my turns. So instead of that I used curl to sign in, get authorization token and using it, send another request with curl to do certain actions. Then I ran that script with the windows task scheduler.
I have the code somewhere, I'll look into it when I get home if you still need help with this.